# Can't access std vector iterator _Ptr on Mac

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator, std

On Visual Studio this snippet of code works like a charm:

```
auto child = node.childs.begin();
    while (child != node.childs.end()) {
        vector<int> siblings;
        for (auto it : node.childs){
            if (it != *child._Ptr)siblings.push_back( it );
        }
        if (CheckSomething( tree, *child._Ptr, siblings ) > 0) {
            //delete that child
            child = node.childs.erase( child );
        }
        else ++child;
    }
```

but with the same code on XCode I got errors like _Ptr is non existent? is not the same std  library with the same structures? why this happen?

```
File.cpp:1745:22: No member named '_Ptr' in 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Names like _Ptr  are implementation-specific details - you should not be using them in your code. And to be fair, the implementation should make some effort to not allow you to use them.

Comment: Names starting with underscore followed by an upper-case letter are reserved for the implementation and not something you should use in your own code nor access/assume exist in the implementations code. End of story.  Bad developer; no cookie for you.

Comment: I think `*child._Ptr`  should be `(*child)._Ptr` or `child->_Ptr`, because `child` is an iterator.

Comment: To be correct about what you're trying to do: `&*it != &*child`

Answer (score 1):

The specification defines no such member variable. `_Ptr` is an implementation-specific (in this case MSVC-specific) member variable that may or may not exist on other implementations.

Generally names starting with underscores refer to implementation-specific members. Don't ever access those, if you want your code to be portable or not to break between compiler versions.

Comment: Thanks! it explains now, but in that case how do I access an equivalent of _Ptr on Mac?

Comment: @RaúlFernándezHernandez Examine the things provided by the standard [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). See which of them would be an appropriate replacement. I don't know what `_Ptr` refers to on MSVC - it's shouldn't and isn't documented. You might want `.data()`.

Comment: @RaúlFernándezHernandez Might be `if (it != *child)` ?

Comment: @tambre The standard for std::vector doesn't specify any member variables.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, it is not the same library. By accessing `_Ptr` in VS, you relied on implementation behavior, which can change anytime, including when you update VS.

I have no idea what `_Ptr` is (remember: that's implementation defined and should never have been accessed, so it's probably not documented), but have a look at [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (if that is the type of `node.childs`) and see if you can find anything that does the same thing as `_Ptr`.

As a rule of thumb, don't use names that start with one or two underscores.

Comment: silly me haha, thanks! in this case child should be an iterator of a vector<int>

Comment: "don't use names that start with one or two underscores" - to be more precise; the reserved names are those that a) start with an underscore and are followed by an upper-case letter *and* b) *any* name containing two consecutive underscores *anywhere*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If you look at the next point [`[5.10.3.2]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3.2), you'll see that every name starting with an underscore is reserved (but only for the global namespace, but still). Better not to go near identifiers which start with an underscore to be sure.

Comment: @Rakete1111 right, for the global namespace *everything* starting with `_` is reserved as well. And I agree, just *don't* :-)

Comment: Thanks everyone, it works now using (it != *child) as you all suggested.